# How to join only 1 column based on conditions on multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, conditional-statements

I have a mapping table with three columns `old_id1`, `old_id2` and `new_id` in a Google BigQuery table.

After performing some SQL operations on multiple other tables, finally I have a table `data` where I have a column `id` (with other columns) which can have either `old_id1`, `old_id2` or `new_id`. I want to replace `id` column values such that it only has `new_id`s using mapping table to perform some aggregate functions.

It is also acceptable to create another column by joining two tables which consists only `new_id` for each `id`.

Logically,

```
If id == new_id, then pass
If id == old_id1 OR id == old_id2, then id = new_id
```

OR (new column)

```
For each id, find its corresponding new_id and if it exists put it in a new column.
```

EXAMPLE:
`mapping_table`

```
old_id1 old_id2 new_id
o1       o2      n1
oo1      oo2     n2
```

`data`

```
id amount
o1 100
o2 200
n1 300
oo2 100
n2 50
n3 25
```

If I try to find aggregate sum for each unique id, expected outcome:

```
id sum
n1 600
n2 150
n3 25
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as tabulr text and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT new_id AS id, SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM `project.dataset.data` d
JOIN `project.dataset.mapping_table` m
ON id IN (old_id1, old_id2, new_id) 
GROUP BY id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row id  total_amount     
1   n1  600  
2   n2  150
```

> I didn't want to lose the entries from data table whose ids are not in mapping table in any column

```
#standardSQL
WITH map AS (
  SELECT old_id1 id, new_id FROM `project.dataset.mapping_table` UNION ALL
  SELECT old_id2, new_id FROM `project.dataset.mapping_table` 
)
SELECT COALESCE(new_id, id) AS id, SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM `project.dataset.data` d
LEFT JOIN map m
USING(id)
GROUP BY 1
```

this will return

```
Row id  total_amount     
1   n1  600  
2   n2  150  
3   n3  25
```

Comment: great! glad it helped

Comment: I was trying with LEFT JOIN because I didn't want to lose the entries from data table whose ids are not in mapping table in any column.

Comment: I have updated the example of question. How could I achieve that? If I have an id n3 in the data table with no mapping id, I want it to be as it is in the final outcome.

Comment: In standard SQL this would have to be `GROUP BY new_id`, though, because we don't want one result row per `data.id`, but per `mapping_table.new_id`. And when working with multiple tables, I'd always qualify all tables with their table alias to avoid confusion or even ambiguity in  case the other table gets a column with the same name some time.

Comment: usually it is not a good manner on SO updating /changing the initial question - especially after the answer(s) already provided - in such cases it is better to ask/post new question! meantime try CROSS JOIN and transfor ON clause into WHERE clause  - usually this works :o)

Comment: For the n3 entry to work you must left outer join the mapping table and `group by coalesce(m.new_id, d.n3)` and also select the same expression: `select coalesce(m.new_id, d.n3) as id, sum(amount) as total_amount`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - this question for BigQuery - please have this in mind :o)

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant: I must admit I don't know Google's BigQuery. I thought it to be standard compliant.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - not 100% yet

Comment: @loadbox - see update in my answer. if you have any follow up question(s) - please post them as a new question(s) and we will be happy to answer :o)

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant: Hi Mikhail. This got me curious. So, the straight-forward `select coalesce(m.new_id, d.n3) as id, sum(d.amount) as total_amount from project.dataset.data d join project.dataset.mapping_table m on d.id in (m.old_id1, m.old_id2, m.new_id) group by coalesce(m.new_id, d.n3)` does not work? This is SQL92. What is it that BigQuery cannot deal with yet? Can't it group by expressions? Or what else? Do you know? (I hope I'm not bothering.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - replace `join` with `left join` and you will get `LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join`  :o)

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant: Ah, okay, thank you. (And yes, sorry that I forgot to write `left join`, as I originally intended; thanks for the correction.)